# Database migration using Apache Spark

Tags: database, apache-spark, spark-streaming, ignite

I have to perform migration from one abstract database to another (lets for example say from oracle to cassandra) and we want to use Apache Spark Streaming for that. It is not a simple mapping of types of one db to another but also includes complex transformations and validation. A typical case  is to check before validation/transformation some condition of our data in RDD through looking for some relations of this value with values in the whole (maybe also different) dataset  (for example cases when our value from rdd is used in some other table and we want to check this and perform some actions for each occurrence occurrence).

So we have an option of using Apache Ignite with it's shared rdd to solve this problem. And when we will receive such data which will need external check of it's correlation with the other data from the whole migration scope then we will simply go to ignite (which will be used as a temprorary storage for such cases), check correlations and perform all the neccessary actions with our value.

So does smb have such experience and what typical problems we will possibly meet. Is it a good practice  to use such architecture or may be this can be done more efficient and with better design in Spark?

Comment: Hi Stepan, did you succeed with such architecture? Can you share your experience?

Comment: Hi Alexey. We are now on POC stage and spark is a new thing for us so my info may not be completely valid but after some analysis we've found that ignite seems a valid component to be used for storing static datasets  with which we want compare our incoming data during processing(dictionaries etc). And now we are making research and experiments on joining large datasets.  We will have to perform stream-to-stream joins on huge datasets which anyway won't fit in memory and in bad cases they will have to be dropped to a disk.

Comment: In a perfect world where cluster size is large enough to get all our data distributed among nodes, where joins and aggregations are also written perfectly, shuffles are avoided etc then ignite may give us a benefit even in joining not static datasets. But in our case our cluster wont be too large (10 machines max) and so we are on the way of finding an optimal solution for us. I'll also share my experience after we'll complete POC and come to a final design.